# Generalized second derivative test

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, machine-learning, hessian-matrix

We know that the second derivative of a critical point is positive then we have a local minimum, if it is negative we have a local maximum. If we generalize this concept to functions with more variables, we must verify the sign of the Hessian Matrix H. It is said that if H is defined positive, ie:

$$x^THx>0$$

then we have a local minimum.

1. But why to say that the second derivative in a multidimensional space is positive, you must verify this condition?Why is x multiplied to the left and right of H? I might say something stupid, but wouldn't it be enough to verify that every component of the matrix H is positive and that's it? What is the real concept behind this definition?
2. Another definition, is that if H has all eigenvalues greater than zero, then it is defined positive, and then we have a local minimum. Why is this true? What is the concept behind this definition?
3. All this is true because H is a symmetrical matrix. Why is it important that H is symmetric, for the above definitions? If we don't have a symmetric matrix, how do we calculate its sign?

Comment: Are you following a textbook? Most texts answer all $3$ questions in great detail...

Comment: Yes more than one book, none of them explain why. I want to understand the concept behind it.

Comment: In terms of linear algebra, you have a local minimum if the quadratic form associated to the hessian is definite positive, and it is a local maximum if it is definite negative.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but it is a definition. I would like to understand why. Why is it necessary to have a quadratic form, and it is not enough to check if all the elements of the Hessian Matrix are positive (or negative)?

Comment: Let me find you some texts that definitely prove these things...

Comment: It is most emphatically NOT sufficient that all the entries of $H$ are positive. Consider the function
$$f(x,y)=x^2+3xy+y^2.$$
The origin is a critical point, and the Hessian is
$$H=\pmatrix{2&3\cr3&2\cr}.$$
Yet $f(t,-t)=-t^2<0$ for all $t$, proving that the origin is not a local minimum.

Comment: The catch is that the second derivative of $f$ in the direction $(1,-1)$ (so along the line parametrized as $(t,-t)$) is then
$$(1\ -1)H\pmatrix {1\cr-1\cr}=(-1\ 1)\pmatrix{1\cr-1\cr}=-2<0.$$

Comment: More generally $x^T H x$ calculates the second derivative in the direction of the vector $x$. To have a local minimum (resp. maximum) you want all such directional derivatives to be positive (negative).

Comment: When the components of the vector $x$ have mixed signs, it is possible that the sign of $x^THx$ is negative even though all the entries of $H$ are positive. In yet other words, when we have several variables we can approach the critical point from infinitely many directions. (in sharp contrast to the single variable case). This creates the possibility that in some directions the (restriction of the) function may have a local maximum and in some other directions a local minimum. Exactly when the signs of the quadratic form vary.

Comment: And, last but not least, the analysis of the quadratic form in terms of eigenvalues of its matrix absolutely relies on the matrix being symmetric. The explanation of this is a bit longer. I refer my students to the course in linear algebra for the details even though I do review the idea. If you haven't taken linear algebra, you may have trouble understanding some parts of the explanation.

Comment: Observe that $$\det\pmatrix{2&3\cr 3&2\cr}=-5.$$ The determinant is the product of the eigenvalues, so we know that the eigenvalues have opposite signs. Therefore this Hessian form is indefinite, and we have a saddle point rather than a minimum/maximum.

Comment: I gotta go sleep. We have several users who understand this inside out. They can pick from where I stopped (or fill in the details). This is pretty standard stuff. But not too easy the first time you see it, because you really need to combine various stuff from calculus AND linear algebra. It possible to pass linear algebra, with a good grade even, without internalizing all this.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, it's a bit clearer. But it is not enough for me to understand completely. Unfortunately there are some concepts that are not explained in the books.